# How to get selected text in element Editor Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

The Editor element does not have a selectionStart property like the Entry element.  How can I create this property using render?  I can't use the Entry element because I need a Multi strings element.

my task is to get the text that is selected by the user in the Editor Element

Comment: Does this link about [How do I select and perform actions upon selected text in a .NET MAUI Editor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77603874/how-do-i-select-and-perform-actions-upon-selected-text-in-a-net-maui-editor) answer your question?